# Sails.js redirects to example.com on production

Tags: sails.js

In dev mode everything works great, but when on production mode, somehow sails redirects me to https://example.com

Not sure, why. Any ideas?

[image: Server console, and user redirect snapshots]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the `baseUrl` in `config/env/production.js` from `example.com` to `localhost:1337`. When running in production mode, these settings are applied to the sails server.

Comment: Adding localhost:1337 results in an error (in index.js file). Adding http:/localhost:1337 results in too many redirects when accessing localhost:1337

Answer (score 2):

Please set `baseUrl` in `production.js` excluding port.

It means, if you want to serve `http://localhost:1337`, please just set `baseUrl: 'http://localhost'`.

Don't set `baseUrl: 'http://localhost:1337'`

In the custom hook code, they compares `req.hostname` and `url.host` to decide whether calling redirection or not.
While `req.hostname` cannot have port, [`url.host`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/url.html#url_url_host) can have port if you set it with port.